# Going through list from the end after split()

Tags: python, list, split

```
for item in "1,2,3,4,5,6".split(","):
```

I need to reverse the list to have first 6, then 5... Does an idea come to your mind how to do it more effectively than reverse it first and then use it? Some function I don't know yet?

Comment: Expected order for `"1,2,3,4,6,5"`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary 5,6,4,3,2,1

Comment: *through Typo in title

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`reversed()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed):

```
for item in reversed("1,2,3,4,5,6".split(",")):
```

Demo:

```
>>> for item in reversed("1,2,3,4,5,6".split(",")):
...     print item
... 
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Comment: That's exactly the thing I was looking for. Thank you.